# Bootstrap footer

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Es mi primera vez con bootstrap y css en general.
Resulta que estoy haciendo un header y un footer y necesitaría que el footer tuviera un tamaño mínimo dependiendo de la página ya sea movil o no.
El footer tiene que estar al final de los datos/recursos del "body" y no seguir la pantalla en ningún momento pero en caso de que el body sea demasiado pequeño que se ponga en la parte inferior de la pantalla.

https://gyazo.com/94714577cea5cb0053682d8f7608cdea

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ya he visto que no se ve el enlace, pido perdón.

De todas formas he encontrado la solución después de navegar unas cuantas horas.
https://medium.com/@kayodeniyi/understanding-the-sticky-footer-trick-1e5686c232b6

Añadimos a todo el contenido de la página menos el footer este tag (recomiendo crear un div y usarlo únicamente para esta clase): `class='wrapper'` y después entre el body y nuestro footer añadiremos un div: `<div class='push'></div>`.
Y para acabar al footer le añadiremos su clase. que ahora modificaremos.`<footer class="footer">`

CSS custom

```
/*Esta parte sirve para poder tener el footer siempre abajo de la página independientemente de la resolución. 
Además en el caso de que haya más texto del que cabe en pantalla el footer irá a la parte del final de ignorando la resolución*/
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  margin-bottom: -70px;  /*Originalmente igual que el footer 100px*/
}

.footer,
.push {
  height: 50px; /*Originalmente igual que el wrapper 100px*/
}
/**/
```

Comment: responder con solo enlaces se considera de baja calidad, edita esto y añade lo relevante